# Algorithm for determining the subject of a NL sentence / question

Tags: nlp, discourse

I'm trying to write code that takes in a natural language sentence and determines what that sentence is about. Not from a list of possible subjects, but just from the input text, the NL sentence.

Most of these sentences will be NL questions.

**What is the best way to determine the subject of a sentence / question; or in other words, what the sentence is about?**

What I am currently doing is finding the nouns in the sentence, but the subject isn't always a noun.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me write the psuedo-code of an algorithm that can do this properly.

Comment: The technical term for what you have in mind is either *topic* (as opposed to *focus*) or alternatively *theme* (as opposed to *rheme*). *Subject* isn't very helpful, as its generally used to mean the *grammatical* subject of a sentence, rather than its 'aboutness'.

Comment: As an aside, i'm a theoretical linguist so don't know much about nlp, but i'd imagine you'd really struggle to find an algorithm that does this anywhere approaching reliably. There's no straightforward mapping from structural position to information-structural role - what is identified as the topic/focus is commonly heavily dependent on context and prosodic cues, at least in a language like English, which has no overt morphosyntactic marking for topics/foci.

Comment: @PElliott I don't think his question is about information structure. If I'm mistaken, a detailed algorithm (in form of pseudocode) is given in [link](http://www.amazon.de/Meaning-Sentence-Semantic-Pragmatic-Aspects/dp/9027718385/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1381100095&sr=8-2&keywords=sgall+meaning).

Comment: @gomangomango I've just noticed that there's a pretty much identical question on linguistics se over here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2643/locating-a-sentences-topic?rq=1

Comment: @Atamiri Have you read that book? Is it in that book?

Comment: @PElliott Hmm, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: As I wrote, an algorithm for topic-recognition is described in the book.

Comment: @Atamiri I bought the book and have it. Where in the book is the algorithm for topic recognition?